# xcode build error when building in parallel

Tags: xcode, continuous-integration, parallel-builds, deriveddata

in a CI/CD system, when multiple concurrent xcode processes run in parallel on the same mac-agent, errors occur with the processing of the shared cache.

Error example:
❌  fatal error: malformed or corrupted AST file: 'could not find file '.../Pods/Firebase/CoreOnly/Sources/module.modulemap' referenced by AST file '~Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/2FKA2K2BK8GI0/ObjectiveC-1KD62J152BYGO.pcm''

in the build on another agent the following error:

❌  fatal error: module file '~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/2FKA2K2BK8GI0/Foundation-A3SOD99KJ0S9.pcm' is out of date and needs to be rebuilt: signature mismatch

add a trigger on the xcode process to read-write data movement in DerivedData

if the process somehow goes on, then wait and start the process in a minute

also think about isolating build threads to xcode
xcode 13.4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took advantage of ruby and sketched out such a script that simply suspends other parallel xcode build processes if the xcodebuild process is already running on the agent.

```html
sleep_time = ((Time.now.to_f - Time.now.strftime("%s").to_f) * 1000000).to_i # 988589 or 153779 or 39680
  case
  when sleep_time > 300000
    sleep_time /= 10000
  when sleep_time > 100000 && sleep_time < 300000
    sleep_time /= 1000
  when sleep_time > 10000 && sleep_time < 100000
    sleep_time /= 1000
  when sleep_time > 1000 && sleep_time < 10000
    sleep_time /= 100
  when sleep_time > 300 && sleep_time < 1000
    sleep_time /= 10
  end
  puts("maximal sleep time = #{sleep_time}")

  # sleep(Random.rand(sleep_time))
  sleep(sleep_time)
  loop do
    xcodebuildProcess = `ps -A | grep xcodebuild | awk '{print $4}'`
    xcodebuildProcesschecker = false
    if xcodebuildProcess.match("Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild")
      xcodebuildProcesschecker = true
      puts 'find Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild'
      sleep(30)
    else
      xcodebuildProcesschecker = false
      puts("xcodebuild process is not running")
      break
    end
    break if xcodebuildProcesschecker == false
  end

  sh("ls -la ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/")
  sh("ls -la ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/") if Dir.exists?("~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/")
  sh("rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/")
  sh("ls -la ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).